# Some issue about PropertiesFactoryBean in spring-framework

Tags: java, spring

I encountered a problem in the project. If I follow the following configuration, I can get the corresponding properties from the service(http://ip:port/api/config)

```
<bean id="configProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>          
            <value>url:http://ip:port/api/config</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But, if I change to the following configuration(I just added a parameter to the URL). It does not work.

```
<bean id="configProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>          
            <value>url:http://ip:port/api/config?key=value</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Do you have the same problem while using PropertiesFactoryBean? Please help me, thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try without **url** ? It should be like this : `<value>http://ip:port/api/config?key=value</value>`

Comment: I have try it, but it doesn't work. It look like that, if there is a ? in the url. Spring will try it as a file pattern and find the resource in the file system. 

@see PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver#getResources